# Is it possible to add data to an Android APK with no impact on the signature?

Tags: android, apk, signature

I would like to add a checksum to an Android APK without breaking the signature. Is there any area of the APK, where it is safe and legal to put such data?

I imagine the folder META-INF is excluded when generating the signature, but I have doubts, whether it is legal to add more files here.

Answer (score 1):

No. That's one of the reasons the cryptographic signature is used in APKs for.

Comment: What would happend, if I added data to an APK not mentioned in MANIFAST.MF? Then I guess, that the signature verification would not be affected?